# How to do Digest Authentication From Business Central with Username Authentication?

Tags: c#, soap, dynamics-business-central

**Here is Main Function From Where I am passing BC200 Parameter**

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        // Create a WebRequest for the URL.

         const string url = "http://desktop-0l30600:20047/BC200";
         const string dir = "/WS/SystemService";
         const string username = "Shahzad Aslam";
         const string password = "Winter123!@#";

         DigestAuthFixer digest = new DigestAuthFixer(url, username, password);
         string strReturn = digest.GrabResponse(dir);
    }
}
```

**End Main Function**

**Digest Authentication Code**

```
   public class DigestAuthFixer
    {
        private static string _host;
        private static string _user;
        private static string _password;
        private static string _realm;
        private static string _nonce;
        private static string _qop;
        private static string _cnonce;
        private static DateTime _cnonceDate;
        private static int _nc;

        public DigestAuthFixer(string host, string user, string password)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            _host = host;
            _user = user;
            _password = password;
        }

        private string CalculateMd5Hash(string input)
        {
            var inputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
            var hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(inputBytes);
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var b in hash)
                sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        private string GrabHeaderVar(string varName,string header)
        {
            var regHeader = new Regex(string.Format(@"{0}=""([^""]*)""", varName));
            var matchHeader = regHeader.Match(header);
            if (matchHeader.Success)
                return matchHeader.Groups[1].Value;
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Header {0} not found", varName));
        }

        private string GetDigestHeader(string dir)
        {
            _nc = _nc + 1;

            var ha1 = CalculateMd5Hash(string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", _user, _realm, _password));
            var ha2 = CalculateMd5Hash(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "GET", dir));
            var digestResponse =
                CalculateMd5Hash(string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2:00000000}:{3}:{4}:{5}", ha1, _nonce, _nc, _cnonce, _qop, ha2));

            return string.Format("Digest username=\"{0}\", realm=\"{1}\", nonce=\"{2}\", uri=\"{3}\", " +
                "algorithm=MD5, response=\"{4}\", qop={5}, nc={6:00000000}, cnonce=\"{7}\"",
                _user, _realm, _nonce, dir, digestResponse, _qop, _nc, _cnonce);
        }

        public string GrabResponse(string dir)
        {
            var url = _host + dir;
            var uri = new Uri(url);

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

            // If we've got a recent Auth header, re-use it!
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_cnonce) &&
                DateTime.Now.Subtract(_cnonceDate).TotalHours < 1.0)
            {
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", GetDigestHeader(dir));
            }

            HttpWebResponse response;
            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                // Try to fix a 401 exception by adding a Authorization header
                if (ex.Response == null || ((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                    throw;

                var wwwAuthenticateHeader = ex.Response.Headers["WWW-Authenticate"];
                _realm = GrabHeaderVar("realm", wwwAuthenticateHeader);
                _nonce = GrabHeaderVar("nonce", wwwAuthenticateHeader);
                _qop = GrabHeaderVar("qop", wwwAuthenticateHeader);

                _nc = 0;
                _cnonce = new Random().Next(123400, 9999999).ToString();
                _cnonceDate = DateTime.Now;

                var request2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
                request2.Headers.Add("Authorization", GetDigestHeader(dir));
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse();
            }
            var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

**End** **Digest Authentication Code**

I am trying to Authenticate BC200 SOAP Request in my C# Code. But Whenever I try to connect it it gives me error 401 Unauthorized and if i look inside Quick watch to request2 parameter it gives below information

[request2 parameter stack in quick watch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9tAu.png)

I am not sure. Am I passing the right parameter of Business Central 200 On-Premise to access SAOP URL? and if I am passing the right parameter then why it is giving 401 unauthorized error? Although I am authenticating inside the business central 200 On-Premise website correctly with username credentials and I also have assigned a thumbprint in BC200 correctly from my pc.

Answer (score 0):

In Business Central, basic authentication requires a web service access key instead of the user password. This method is deprecated for SaaS, but can still be used in on-premises environments.
You can refer to Microsoft documentation for details on the web service access key:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/webservices/web-services-authentication